# $\prod_{i = 1}^{100} \sin ix = 1$

Tags: trigonometry

I have encountered this problem and I do not know how to solve it.
$$\prod_{i = 1}^{100} \sin ix = 1$$I have tried multiplying it with various quantities, such as $\cos x,\ \sin x$. I have also tried organizing the product in pairs of $(\sin x, \sin  100x), \ (\sin  2x, \ \sin  99x)$ and so on, but all these efforts proved to be in vain. I have also multiplied it with the product of cosines, and got to the point of $\prod_{i = 1}^{100} \cos ix$ is also 1. I would like to hear your opinion on it.

Comment: hint: ask yourself what $max(|\sin(t)|)$ for $t$ real

Comment: @PierreCarre I thought it was an identity to be proven. Then I saw your answer and realized my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

All the factors are $\leq 1$ in absolute value. The product can only be 1 if all factors are 1 (in absolute value).

$$
\prod_{i=1}^{n} \sin (ix) = 1 \Rightarrow |\sin (ix)| = 1, \quad i = 1, \cdots, n
$$

As @Andrei pointed out in the comments to this post, there is no such $x$.In fact, one can check that $f_n(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n \sin(i x)$ is, at least, point wise convergent to zero.

Comment: So that means no solution. If $\sin x=\pm 1$, then $\sin2x=0$, so the product is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I thought I should get an easier-to-deal-with expression, but now I see it is much easier.

Comment: @Andrei That's it!